# Must resize window for items to show

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listview

I have a `ListView` which I have bound with a `List`. If I add items to the `List` I must resize my window for the items to appear in my `ListView`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your list implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx).  You may want to use `ObservableCollection<T>` here, as it makes this easy.

If you are binding to a standard `List<T>`, there is no way for the binding system to know that the list's contents have changed.  My guess is that, when you resize the window, the list is rechecking the binding (in order to perform the new layout correctly), and capturing the new elements.  Until you do this, the list's binding never refreshes.  `INotifyCollectionChanged` will fix that.

Comment: I can't for some reason choose ObservableCollection from ObjectModel. See http://i47.tinypic.com/21b3gd3.jpg